# How to store a user object for your Polymer app and make it accessible everywhere

Tags: object, authentication, polymer, accessible

I was wondering what are the best practices to store an user object and make it accessible through my whole Polymer app. Since I'm using a lot of template imports, I'm getting a little bit lost on how to access my user object retrieved from my `<x-login id="xlogin" user="{{user}}"></x-login>`  template imported by my `my-app` template. I'm using `<firebase-auth>` for authentication.

Let's say I'm five template levels deep and I want to access my `refreshToken` which is in my `{{user}}` object, what is the best way to get this?

- Do I have to do a querySelector for my element with id `#login`?
- Or do I have to pass the user object through all my nested elements?
- Or do I have to include `<firebase-auth app-name="projectMeta"
  id="auth" user="{{user}}"></firebase-auth>` in all my pages where I
  want to get my userdata?
- Or are there better/cleaner ways to achieve this?

Comment: To extend this question; I'm working with `paper-toast` now. What is the best way to only have to include this element once and make it accessible throughout my whole polymer app?